# POST, GET, Onsubmit - что лучше для простого перехода по URL с передаваемой переменной?

Tags: javascript, php, html, frontend

Что выгоднее применять для простого перехода по URL с передаваемой переменной "code"

1. `<form method="POST"` - здесь всё ясно, через сессию POST, далее редирект по `header("Location:` .
2. `<form method="get" target="_self" action="page.php?code="<?php print($_POST['code']); ?>">` - здесь вот такиv образом. Мне кажется самый некорректный вариант.
3. `onsubmit="window.location = 'weather.php?code='+code.value; return false;"` - здесь просто и здорово. JavaScript и здесь выручает.

Верно ли я понимаю, что для простого перехода по кнопки на URL с вписанием в URL переменной, третий вариянт самый простой и самый оптимальный для реализации?

Comment: Что за переменная code? Для чего она служит? Что значит "простые вещи"?

Comment: Если есть сабмит на сервер,  а потом перенаправление, то лучше это делать на сервере

Comment: Если rest - то управление переходит на клиент и перенаправление задаёт он

Answer (score 1):

1. Для простого перехода по URL в протоколе HTTP предусмотрен метод GET
2. Для простой реализации метода GET в HTML используются *гиперссылки*. Поэтому если код находится на сервере, и надо передать его на клиент с тем, чтобы потом можно было по нему кликнуть, пишем так

   ```
    <a href="page.php?"<?= http_build_query(['code' => $code]) ?>">Переход</a>
   ```
3. Если переход необходимо осуществить после обработки POST запроса, то это делается HTTP заголовком Location

   ```
    header("Location: page.php?".http_build_query(['code' => $_POST['code']]));
    die;
   ```
4. Если все происходит на клиенте, а примеры на РНР добавлены в вопрос от балды, то можно использовать яваскрипт и window.location

Comment: Я как раз и выбираю их трёх. Это мой код. Мой проект. Методом POST передавать одну переменную не считаю рациональным. Метод POST, в то время когда я учился, а я самоучка, был для передачи чего-то на сервер или в БД. Либо для чего-то более важного и защищённого. (Надеюсь PHP не кардинально изменился).

Comment: в Вашем варианте №2 - переменная $code должна уже быть.
Она же у меня формируется как раз таки из выбора пользователя из datalist - пользователь вписал город, кликает и datalist уже ассоциирует город с кодом города.
Я постарался в примере 3 уйти от лишнего шага.
Т.е. человек вписал и уже скрипт взял код города и при клике на сервер пойдёт уже сформированная корректная URL.
Моё понимание этого механизма. Поправьте, если заблуждаюсь.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего этого не ясно. В первых двух вариантах нужный код находится на сервере (причем во втором еще и в переменной $_POST почему-то) - то есть его надо сначала передать на клиент, а потом уже с клиента куда-то отправить.  Вам надо определиться сначала самому, а потом уже спрашивать. Если код на клиенте, и нет препятствий к использованию яваскрипта, то 4 пункт в моем ответе тоже есть.